# SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings In iNTELIJI LENGUAGE JAVA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When trying to compile my Maven project in IntelliJ, it shows an error with the `mvn install` command, also with the `mvn install -DskipTests` command, it shows me in the surefire-reports and when executing the tests, the following:

```
SLF4J: Class Path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Link found in [jar:file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/1.6.1/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/ impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: Link found in [jar:file:/C:/Users/admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.17.1/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.17.1 .jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]

SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
```

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ZzX8.png)

I hope you can help, I've been trying everything for days.

I tried to delete the duplicate folder, put dependencies but nothing.

Comment: Welcome! Please include your dependencies in the question (`pom.xml`, `build.gradle`, or whatever you’re using). It’s also a good idea to tag the build tool that you’re using. Did you read the page linked in the error message? If there’s something you found unclear in it, that would also be good to include in your question. “I’ve been trying everything” should be replaced with _what specifically_ you’ve tried.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.